# I have a problem where it says cannot convert "int to boolean" I need assistance

Tags: java

This is the question:

> 1. Create a method called isFive(). The method will take in a single integer as a parameter. If the integer is 5, return "The number is
>    Five" Otherwise, return "The number is not Five"
> 2. Create a method called positiveOrNegative(). The method will take in a single double as a parameter. If the double is positive, return
>    "Positive" Otherwise, return "Negative" (This includes 0)
> 3. Create a method called evenOrOdd(). The method will take in a single integer as a parameter. If the integer is even, return "Even"
>    Otherwise, return "Odd"
> 4. Create a method called isHello(). The method will take in a single String as a parameter. If the String is "Hello", return
>    "The word is Hello" Otherwise, return "The word is not Hello"

This is the code I used

class PP31 {
public static void main (String args[]) {

```
}

public static int isFive(int num1) {
    if (num1 == 5) {
        System.out.println("The Number is Five");
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("The number is not Five");
    }                       
}

public static double positiveOrNegative(double d1) {
    if (d1 >= 1) {
        System.out.println("Positive");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Negative");
    }
}

public static int evenOrOdd(int i2) {
    if (i2 /= 2) {                       //This is where is says that "int cannot be converted to boolean"
        System.out.println("Even");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Odd");
    }
}

public static String isHello(String s1) {
    if (s1 == "Hello") {
        System.out.println("The word is Hello");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The word in not Hello");
    }
}
```

}

here is the test that goes with it

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class PP31Test {

    @Test
    void isFiveTest1() {
        assertEquals("The number is not Five", PP31.isFive(4));
    }

    @Test
    void isFiveTest2() {
        assertEquals("The number is Five", PP31.isFive(5));
    }

    @Test
    void isFiveTest3() {
        assertEquals("The number is not Five", PP31.isFive(0));
    }

    @Test
    void isFiveTest4() {
        assertEquals("The number is not Five", PP31.isFive(-5));
    }

    @Test
    void positiveOrNegativeTest1() {
        assertEquals("Positive", PP31.positiveOrNegative(4));
    }

    @Test
    void positiveOrNegativeTest2() {
        assertEquals("Negative", PP31.positiveOrNegative(-3));
    }

    @Test
    void positiveOrNegativeTest3() {
        assertEquals("Negative", PP31.positiveOrNegative(0));
    }

    @Test
    void positiveOrNegativeTest4() {
        assertEquals("Positive", PP31.positiveOrNegative(999));
    }

    @Test
    void positiveOrNegativeTest5() {
        assertEquals("Negative", PP31.positiveOrNegative(-999));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest1() {
        assertEquals("Even", PP31.evenOrOdd(4));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest2() {
        assertEquals("Odd", PP31.evenOrOdd(3));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest3() {
        assertEquals("Even", PP31.evenOrOdd(1000));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest4() {
        assertEquals("Even", PP31.evenOrOdd(0));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest5() {
        assertEquals("Odd", PP31.evenOrOdd(999));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest6() {
        assertEquals("Even", PP31.evenOrOdd(-4));
    }

    @Test
    void evenOrOddTest7() {
        assertEquals("Odd", PP31.evenOrOdd(-3));
    }

    @Test
    void isHelloTest1() {
        assertEquals("The word is Hello", PP31.isHello("Hello"));
    }

    @Test
    void isHelloTest2() {
        assertEquals("The word is not Hello", PP31.isHello("Bye"));
    }

    @Test
    void isHelloTest3() {
        assertEquals("The word is not Hello", PP31.isHello("Hello!"));
    }

    @Test
    void isHelloTest4() {
        assertEquals("The word is not Hello", PP31.isHello("hello"));
    }

    @Test
    void isHelloTest5() {
        assertEquals("The word is not Hello", PP31.isHello(""));
    }

    @Test
    void isHelloTest6() {
        assertEquals("The word is not Hello", PP31.isHello("Hello "));
    }



}
```

Comment: This is Java code, not JavaScript.

Comment: First, this is Java, not JavaScript. Second, could you provide what the code inside those methods is as well as where exactly it says "cannot convert int to boolean"?

Comment: Remember to turn your code into [mcve] form: start removing tests until the error disappears. Then show _that_ test (after looking at it yourself, to verify that the argument and return types are what they should have been).

Comment: Please don't assume how the syntax works. `if (i2 /= 2)` does not test if a number is divisible by two. It divides i2 by two and reassigns the result to itself. You have to use `if(i2 % 2 == 0)`

Comment: I have now provided the code that I need help with

Comment: You're not following the directions. For example, the isFive() method should return a String. Instead you are printing the String rather than returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `/=` does not exist on Java. You can check if a number is divisible by another using `%`:

```java
public static int evenOrOdd(int i2) {
    if (i2 % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Even");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Odd");
    }
}
```

Side note: this will also raise a compiler error since you're not returning an integer as defined in the method signature. Since you're using it with tests, you can change the return type to string and returning the messages instead of printing them:

```java
public static String evenOrOdd(int i2) {
    if (i2 % 2 == 0) {
        return "Even";
    }
    else {
        return "Odd";
    }
}
```

Comment: re *The operator /= does not exist*.  Sure it does. See [3.12 in the Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) and also [15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26).  It doesn't do what the OP expected, but it certainly exists.

Comment: @iggy According to [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) ("You can also combine the arithmetic operators with the simple assignment operator to create compound assignments"), this is a compound assignment and I was referring to that.

Comment: but then I still don't understand you saying `/=` does not exist. "You can combine..." surely says it exists?  (Though I have to say I prefer the JLS wording, where .`/=` is an operator in its own right, rather than a 'combination' of assignment and `/`).  I may be quiibling about semantics at this point.

Comment: @iggy I said the *operator* /= does not exist, not the compound assignment /=, as I was based on the link I've sent.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for the `%` operator, which will return the 'rest' of it. If it's 0, it's even otherwise odd.

Also, none of yours methods need a return type, meaning all of them should be `void`.